Expectation of reciprocal residual sum of squares
Consider an IID sample $X_1 , \cdots, X_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$, then what can we say about the expectation of the reciprocal residuals when projecting onto every other point? That is can we compute
$$
E \Big [ \frac{1}{||r_i||^2} \Big ] = E \Big [ \frac{1}{X_i^T (I - P_i^\perp) X_i} \Big ],
$$
where $P_i^\perp$ is the projection matrix onto $X^c_i:= \{ X_1, \cdots, X_n \} \backslash \{X_i\}$.
This comes from considering the diagonal components of the precision matrix. I suspect the expectation is infinite, but I'm not able to show it. I've also been assuming $X_i^TX_i = 1$ to make matters simpler.
I've tried to apply tower property to the diagonal terms due to $P_i^\perp$ depending on $X_i^c$
$$E[ \frac{1}{1 - X_i^TP_iX_i}] = E[ E[ \frac{1}{1 - X_i^TP_iX_i}|X_i^c]] = E[ E[ \frac{1}{1 - tr (P_iX_iX_i^T)}|X_i^c]].
$$
A possibly simpler problem would instead be considering
$$
E \Big [ \sum_{j \not = i} \frac{r_i \cdot r_j}{||r_i||^2 ||r_j||^2} \Big ] = E \Big [\sum_{j \not = i} \frac{(X_i - P_iX_i)(X_j - P_jX_j)}{||X_i - P_iX_i||^2||X_j - P_jX_j||^2} \Big ] 
$$
as I suspect the off-diagonal terms are much better behaved and in total average to 0.
But the terms of interest being in the denominator keep thwarting any of the standard methods for computing expectations.
For the off-diagonal sum I've gotten
$$
\begin{align}
    r_i \cdot r_j &= (X_i - P_iX_i)^T (X_j - P_jX_j)\\
                &= X_i^T (I - P_i)(I - P_j) X_j\\
                &= X_i^T (I - P_i - P_j + P_iP_j) X_j\\
                &= X_i^TX_j - X_i^T P_iX_j - X_i^TP_j X_j + X_i^TP_iP_j X_j\\
                &= X_i^T X_j - X_i^T X_j - X_i^T P_j X_j + X_i^TP_i(P_jX_j)\\
                &= X_i^TP_iP_jX_j-X_i^T P_jX_j 
\end{align}
$$
But I have yet to figure out what the sum might look like
I believe I might be overcomplicating things so any thoughts on this computation would be greatly appreciated!!

First, what do you mean by residuals of a "dataset"?  Second, assuming you intend something like regressing one variable (as the response) against the others (as the explanatory variable) and are assuming some reasonable distribution of the errors (indeed, what are you assuming about them?), then the expected reciprocal can be finite provided the residual degrees of freedom exceeds $1.$

Added more details! I had assumed I was using standard definitions sorry about that

It depends.
Suppose your points fall on a lattice. There's then a (small but) non-zero probability that $r_i$ is zero, so the expectation of $1/\|r_i\|^2$ is definitely infinite.
Also, for any distribution, if $n\geq d$ then you will typically have $r_i=0$.
At the other extreme, suppose you have a spherical Gaussian distribution and $n<d-1$.  You're looking at the distance from a random point to a random subspace of dimension $n-1<d-2$, so $1/\|r_i\|^2$ will be some sort of scaled inverse chisquared distribution with at least 2df, and will have finite expectation.
